# Cannot create a new agent in dialogflow, saving goes to "canceled"

Tags: dialogflow-es, agent

I've been trying to create a new agent in DialogFlow. I have one agent and that has problems. (Using share never adds reviewers or developers after I press save.)

So I decided to create another agent - a new agent. I enter a name, time zone, click the create button.... it turns yellow and says "saving".... and then it turns orange and says "canceled." There is no explanation or any help document I can find that identifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is... I have no idea why it works now but it appears there are account problems.

I went to Fulfillment and noticed the inline editor was off. I tried to turn it on and it would go on and then go back to disabled on its own. Wouldn't work. Went back to look again an hour later, same problem. Went to the Share portion about 10 minutes later to try to add a developer just one more time - and this time it worked. I went to Fulfillment and suddenly inline editor is turned on.

For at least 24 hours it didn't work. My developer claimed not to have access and when I looked, nothing in Share. Now all of a sudden it's working and I was able to readd the developer.